# No devuelve datos o crea usuario cuando hago llamada a API REST

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, servidor, error404

He creado una API REST de usuarios que me funcionaba. Posteriormente, introduje el bcrypt y el jwt. EL bcrypt está en el modelo de la base de datos. El jwt, funciona, pero aún no esta como middleware en la ruta de usuarios.

He ido a probar la ruta de usuarios y me devuelve un error 404.
He anulado todo lo de bcrypt y jwt para probar si es lo que me daba error por estar a medias, y tampoco me funciona

He revisado el `controller` de usuarios, la ruta y en el archivo de server y no consigo encontrar donde puede estar el error

No encuentro donde ha dejado de tener acceso a los datos que solicito desde postman con los endpoints

Si busco los usuarios que tengo en la base de datos mediante la terminal de mongo sí me los muestra

Archivo del modelo `User`:

```js
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const userSchema = new Schema({ //? FALTAN
  username: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 20,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true,
    //unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  mail: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true,
    minlength: 7,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
   },
  password: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    maxlength: 150
  },
  
});

//userSchema.plugin(mongooseUniqueValidator);

//TODO ENCRIPTACION PASSWORD
//*  metodo static lo encripta y lo compara ante de instanciar
//* el nombre despues staticts lo escoges tu
// userSchema.statics.encryptPassword = async (password) => {
//   const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
//   return await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)
// }

// userSchema.statics.comparePassword = async (password, recivePassword) => {
//   //* devuelve true o false
//   return await bcrypt.compare(password, recivePassword)
// }

userSchema.set('toJSON', {
  transform: (document, convertObject) => {
    convertObject.id = convertObject._id
    delete convertObject._id
    delete convertObject.__v
    //delete convertObject.password
  }
});

const User = model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Archivo `controller`:
(no muestro la importación a la base de datos porque está hecha)

```js
async function getUsers(req, res, next) {
  const users = await User.find({})
  
  res.status(200).json(users)
};

async function createUser(req, res, next) {
  const {
    username,
    mail,
    password
  } = req.body

  const newUser = new User({
    username,
    mail,
    password
  })

  try {
    const savedUser = await newUser.save()
   
    res.status(201).json(savedUser)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    next(err)
  }
};
```

Archivo de `routes`:

```js
const {
  getUser,
  getUsers,
  createUser,
  uptapeUser,
  deleteUser
} = require('../controllers/usersController')

//* Routes
//* Ruta principal
//! quiza cambiarla de sitio
// router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
//   res.status(200).json({
//     message: "Ruta principal"
//   })
// next()
// });


router.get('/api/users/:id', getUser);
router.get('/api/users/', getUsers);
router.post('/api/users', createUser);
router.put('/api/users/:id', uptapeUser);
router.delete('/api/users/:id', deleteUser);

module.exports = router;
```

Archivo `server`:

```js
const routesUser = require('./routes/userRoutes')

app.use("/api/users", routesUser);
```

Respuesta de Postman:
[image: Respuesta postman:]

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el mensaje 404 tal como lo devuelve tu aplicación a Postman?

Comment: No se si se ve la imagen de postman

Comment: A simple vista le estás anteponiendo a las rutas "/api/users", y luego en las rutas vuelves a poner '/api/users/', por lo que al llamarlas deberías llamar a localhost:xxx/api/users/api/users..

Comment: Muchas gracias Luís S. Romero Ya lo tengo solucionado